# Navigation bar alignment

Tags: html, navbar

This is my code at the moment. I want it to produce a navigation bar with the image and text next to it on the same line on the far left (which it does) and all the menu items which are in the class="top_info" on the same line except they are pulled a bit to the right. Can someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <style>
    body {background: ; margin: ; }
    #container {width: ; margin:; background: #333300 ;   }
    #header {color: white;}
    #logo { font-size: 18pt;}
    #logo img {float: left ;}
    #logo span {color:orange; }



    .top_info {float:left;  color:white;}

        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div id="container">

            <!--header-->   
            <div id="header">

                <div id="logo"><img src="http://www.townplanning.com.au/app/theme/default/design/images/header/logo.png"><span>TOWNPLANNING</span>.COM.AU</p></div>

                <div class="top_info">CONTACT US</div>
                <div class="top_info">BLOG</div>
                <div class="top_info">NEWS</div>
                <div class="top_info">PREVIOUS VCAT DECISIONS</div>
                <div class="top_info">PLANNING SCHEMES</div>
                <div class="top_info">WHAT IS TOWN PLANNING?</div>
                <div class="top_info">MAP</div>
                <div class="top_info">ABOUT</div>
                <div class="top_info">HOME</div>

        </div> <!--div header end-->

    </div> <!--DIV CONTAINTER end-->
```

Comment: Check this:-
http://jsfiddle.net/x2betuua/

Comment: should the menu be in the same line with the logo or in the second line?

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming that the logo and the text should be in first line and menu
   should be in the second line, i have edited the code.

Please see the fiddle:**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/orj2u8x1/4/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">

            <!--header-->   
            <div id="header">

                <div id="logo"><img src="http://www.townplanning.com.au/app/theme/default/design/images/header/logo.png"/><span>TOWNPLANNING</span>.COM.AU</div>
<ul class="top_info">
                <li >CONTACT US</li>
                <li >BLOG</li>
                <li >NEWS</li>
                <li >PREVIOUS VCAT DECISIONS</li>
                <li >PLANNING SCHEMES</li>
                <li >WHAT IS TOWN PLANNING?</li>
                <li >MAP</li>
                <li >ABOUT</li>
                <li >HOME</li>
                </ul>
        </div> <!--div header end-->

    </div> <!--DIV CONTAINTER end-->
```

**CSS**:

```
#container { margin:0; background: #333300 ;overflow:auto;   }
#header {color: white;}
#logo { font-size: 18pt;}
#logo img {float: left ;}
#logo span {color:orange; }
ul{padding:0;}
.top_info li{  color:white;}
ul li{display:inline-block;list-style:none;}
```

- It is always best practice to create menu's using `ul li`. and styling
  them to `display:inline-block` which will make them appear in single
  line.
- I have applied the class to the `ul` tag , repeating it so many times
  in a `div` is not good practice.

2.Assuming that the logo and the menu should be in the same line,
Please see the fiddle for that: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w5mhfL2t/)**

**CSS:**

```
#container { margin:0; background: #333300 ; overflow:auto;  }
 #header {color: white;}
#logo { float:left;font-size: 18pt;}
#logo img {float: left ;}
#logo span {color:orange; }
.top_info li{  color:white;}
ul li{display:inline-block;list-style:none;}
```